# redirect website to only one domain using hooks CI

Tags: php, redirect

This is how I define my base URL:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://royalarcdevelopments.ca/';
```

what happens is if i open this url using the path `http://royalarcdevelopments.ca` , `royalarcdevelopments.ca` it loads fine for both!

But when I load it using the URL `www.royalarcdevelopments.ca` I receive an error:

now i've done some research and found out that `http://royalarcdevelopments.ca` and `www.royalarcdevelopments.ca` are logically two different domains so i developed a way that i can create a hook for controller and check if my website is accessed using  `www` it should redirect it to `http` domain path here's my code

```
<?php
class Pre_controller_uneeb {

    function redirect(){

        $name=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
        $return_path=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        if (strpos($name, 'www') !== false) {
         header("Location: http://royalarcdevelopments.ca$return_path");
        }

    }
}
?>
```

this logic works perfectly now! wherever in the website i use `www` it redirects me to `http` keeping the `uri` same and in end result the user doesnt feel any difference and i dont get any `cross domain origin policy errors` now the only issue is the hook is hard coded you can see i have to manually type the fullpath i tried getting the `base_url()` inside the hook but it is returning an error is there any way to make it generic?

moreover this is how my htaccess looks right now!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Just as a comment: I don't do this in PHP. If you use CPanel, Plesk, or any other server admin package, you can usually configure it there. Your PHP code should preferably never generate an error, just because another subdomain was used. If you use Apache you could configure this in the .htacces file.

Comment: Don't you have access to the $config variable inside your hook?If you don't then you can possibly use "global $config;" to get access and use $config for your redirection.However I agree with KIKO that there are probably better ways to do this.

Comment: how can i do it using htaccess? i've added the htaccess code also

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to do this sort of thing in the HT Access before it actually gets to PHP.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the hostname is NOT www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
# 301 redirect to the same resource on www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co\.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i've disabled the hooks for now but it is taking me to https://sedo.com/uk/?partnerid=48623 when i load the website